# Python way of doing this for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following piece of code:

```
for item in packages:
    if item["name"] == dependency_to_install:
        dependencies = item["requires"]
        for dependency in dependencies:
            get_dependency(packages, dependency, requirements)
        requirements.append(item["name"])
```

Is there a python way of doing all this in one line of code?

Thank you in advance!

**EDDITED:**

Or this is good enough and I don't need to look for better one, because this is self explanatory?

Comment: There probably is (a way to do it in one line in Python) and it's probably bad (i.e., it's not the Python way, i.e., not pythonic).

Comment: You mean a list comprehension

Comment: As @Stefan Pochmann said it's probably bad

Comment: As others have alluded to, *shorter != better*. One-liners have their place, but bytes are cheap and readability is more important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is (probably a list comprehension), but don't do it!

I'll attach a [quote](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) which is probably relevant:

> Beautiful is better than ugly.
>   **Explicit is better than implicit**.
>   **Simple is better than complex**.
>   **Readability counts**

What you can do, however, is to *at most* remove `dependencies = item["requires"]` if you're not using anywhere else:

```
for item in packages:
    if item["name"] == dependency_to_install:
        for dependency in item["requires"]:
            get_dependency(packages, dependency, requirements)
        requirements.append(item["name"])
```

---

As @[Stefan Pochmann](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409979/python-way-of-doing-this-for-loop/44410242?noredirect=1#comment75819573_44410242) suggested, your naming can also be improved. You might want to rename `item` to `package`.

Comment: Something else I'd do is rename `item` to `package`. Also, it looks weird to append `item["name"]` after I found out that it equals `dependency_to_install` (I guess that might change in the `get_dependency` call? It's weird.)

Comment: @StefanPochmann thought of this, but the question lacks context so I decided not to give any other suggestions. However, changing `item` to `package` looks fair enough. I'll add it if you're okay with it